# How to re write code without react.usememo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks. I need to rewrite following snippet without hooks.Please help me.

```
const subHeaderComponentMemo = React.useMemo(() => {
    const handleClear = () => {
      if (filterText) {
        setResetPaginationToggle(!resetPaginationToggle);
        setFilterText('');
      }
    };

    return <FilterComponent onFilter={e => setFilterText(e.target.value)} onClear={handleClear} filterText={filterText} />;
  }, [filterText, resetPaginationToggle]);
```

Comment: You can replace React.useMemo with  React.memo

Comment: This is not the use for `useMemo` you've probably want `React.memo`